# How to source invoice record's line item details on customer payment advanced pdf template?

Tags: pdf, netsuite, payment, suitescript2.0, invoice

I am trying to show invoice line level items on payment receipt's  advanced pdf template. Is it possible? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I meant that is it possible with advanced pdf only without scripting. have you solution now???

Answer (score 0):

Yes, This can be done.

A User Event Script of type beforeLoad can use the script context's type field to run for 'print' events.

You can then look up custom data and add it to your record as custom fields and lists.

Your PDF template can check for the existence of those fields and lists and display them appropriately.

Some Typescript to get you started. Note this was doing the opposite of what you asked - it lists payments on a printed invoice.

```js
export function beforeLoad(ctx: EntryPoints.UserEvent.beforeLoadContext){

    if(ctx.type == ctx.UserEventType.PRINT && ctx.newRecord && ctx.newRecord.id){

const payments = search.create(...).run().getRange({start:0, end:1000}).map...);

var paymentsList = form.addSublist({
        id:'custpage_links',
        type: ui.SublistType.STATICLIST,
        label:'Applied'
    });

    paymentsList.addField({
        id:'doc',
        type:ui.FieldType.TEXT,
        label:'Document'
    })

    paymentsList.addField({
        id:'type',
        type:ui.FieldType.TEXT,
        label:'Type'
    });

    paymentsList.addField({
        id:'total',
        type:ui.FieldType.CURRENCY,
        label:'total'
    });

    payments.forEach((pmnt, idx)=>{
        paymentsList.setSublistValue({
            id:'doc',
            line:idx,
            value:pmnt.doc
        })
        paymentsList.setSublistValue({
            id:'type',
            line:idx,
            value:mapAppliedType(pmnt.type, pmnt.method)
        });
         paymentsList.setSublistValue({
            id:'total',
            line:idx,
            value:''+ pmnt.total
        });
    });
```

and then on the transaction pdf template side:

```
    <#assign appliedLines = []>
    <#assign hasPayment = false>
    <#if record.custpage_links?has_content>
        <#list record.custpage_links as link>
            <#if link.type?has_content && link.type != 'Total'>
                <#if appliedLines?seq_contains(link.type)>
                <#else>
                    <#assign hasPayment = true>
                    <#assign appliedLines = appliedLines + [link.type]>
                    <#assign typeApplied = 0>
                    <#list record.custpage_links as pymnt>
                        <#if pymnt.type == link.type>
                            <#assign typeApplied = typeApplied + pymnt.total>
                        </#if>
                    </#list>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="5" align="right"><b>${link.type}</b></td>
                        <td align="right"><i>(${typeApplied?string.currency})</i></td>
                    </tr>
                </#if>
            </#if>
        </#list>
    </#if>
    <#if hasPayment == false>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5" align="right"><b>${record.amountpaid@label}</b></td>
            <td align="right">${record.amountpaid}</td>
        </tr>
    </#if>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply bknights! But as per your code is it adding payment data on invoice record? I want to print payment pdf from payment record itself.

Comment: That was the point of the 'get you started' comment :-). What I posted is a basic approach to adding related info to a transaction's PDF template. If you are not a coder who can take this as a hint and run with it you should likely find one who can.  (Unless you have time and a desire to learn to code)